# Script to remove files based on threshold value

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have some old file in my Linux server and I need to remove those files which are older than 5 days based on the threshold value.

```
log_space_checker() {
        Use=$(df -kh /logs | awk 'END{gsub("%",""); print $4}');
        DATAUSE=$(df -kh /logs | awk 'END{gsub("%",""); print $4}');
}

remove_files(){
        RemoveFiles="/logs/abc/abc.log.*"
        find "$RemoveFiles" -mtime +1 -type f -delete
        }

disk_space_monitor() {
        log_space_checker;

        if [[ $DATAUSE -gt $TH ]] ; then
                remove_files;
        fi

}

TH=7

disk_space_monitor
```

Is the script correct?

Comment: suggest you change the `-delete` to `-print` and review its behaviour.  create files with old timestamps using `touch` if needed too.

Comment: what is the use of `Use` variable here ?

Comment: do you really have a directory called `"/logs/abc/abc.log.*"` (with star at the end of the name)?

Comment: `df -kh` would ask for output both in kB and in "human readable" (variable units). Also the fourth column (counting from 1) of GNU coreutils `df` output is the available space, not the percentage.

Comment: This is one of those times when you _don't_ want to quote a variable. In `remove_files()` you have `RemoveFiles="/logs/abc/abc.log.*"`. To expand that with a shell glob (so that the `*` matches as a wildcard rather than a literal asterisk) you must _not_ quote it, so `find $Remotefiles ...`

Comment: Not a duplicate. Notice the threshold determination that's also a requirement here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me, I'd go for something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#

########################################################################
#
log_space_checker() {
    local target="$1"                 # Log file template
    local directory="${target%/*}"    # Directory holding log files
    df -k "$directory" | awk 'NR>1 {print gensub("^.* ([1-9][0-9]*)%.*", "\\1", 1)}'
}

########################################################################
#
remove_files(){
    local logfiles="$1"               # Log file template
    find $logfiles -mtime +1 -type f -print ## -delete
}

########################################################################
#
disk_space_monitor() {
    local threshold="$1"              # Threshold%
    local target="$2"                 # Log files to delete 
    local pct_used=$(log_space_checker "$2");

    if [[ $pct_used -gt $threshold ]]
    then
        remove_files "$2"
    fi
}

########################################################################
# Go
#
threshold=7                           # % usage above which we will delete
logfiles='/logs/abc/abc.log.*'        # ...log files matching this pattern

disk_space_monitor "$threshold" "$logfiles"
```

Comment: @Jasen thanks for your input but the script that you have provide has some error i am trying to fix it through the online tool.

can you let me know do i need to give my current directory in place of $2 (local target="$2")

i am a new learner so bit getting confused :)

Comment: @shabaz, no bug, i should have looked closer.

Comment: @roanma, no bug... I was misreading it.